GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file after an upgrade to apache camel 4.8.0
Following an upgrade to camel-apache 4.8.0, I start to face this excepetion:
GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: data/disclosure/ClientSettings.txt.
Caused by: InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile on:
Message.
Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile to the required type: java.io.InputStream. Exchange[].
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile to the required type: java.io.InputStream.
Caused by: NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile to the required type: java.io.InputStream."
"stack":"o.a.c.c.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: data/disclosure/DisclClientSettings.txt
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:325)
at o.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:342)
at o.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:154)
at o.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:208)
at o.a.c.p.e.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.doRun(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:808)
at o.a.c.p.e.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:714)
at o.a.c.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.doRun(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:199)
ato.a.c.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:189)
at o.a.c.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.tryExecuteReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:166)
at o.a.c.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
at o.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163) at o.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.processNonTransacted(CamelInternalProcessor.java:347)
at o.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:323)
at o.a.c.c.netty.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:149)
at o.a.c.c.netty.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:111)
at o.a.c.c.n.http.handlers.HttpServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(HttpServerChannelHandler.java:212)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)... 10 frames truncated
Any help will be much appreciated!
    .pollEnrich("sftp://" + ftpServerProperties.INSTANCE.getFtpConnection() +
            "?username=" + raw(CommonProperties.INSTANCE.getFtpUsername()) +
            "&password=" + raw(CommonProperties.INSTANCE.getFtpPassword()) +
            "&preferredAuthentications=password" +
            "&fileName=" + ClientSettingsProperties.INSTANCE.getFtpFile() +
            "&noop=false" +
            "&disconnect=true" +
            "&useUserKnownHostsFile=false" +
            "&maximumReconnectAttempts=3" +
            "&reconnectDelay=" + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1) +"&binary=true")
    })
    .to("file://data/destination")

I expect file to be copied as usual
